# setTimeout not working on click event with Packery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a delay to the resetItems method in Packery. I have added a timeout to the function below, but it still triggers immediately on click.

What am I missing? Should it wrap around the line below as well? I tried that but then the function didn't work at all (but then I'm not saying I did it *right*...)

```
var $container = $('.packery');

$container.packery({
itemSelector: '.item',
gutter: 0
});

$(".reset").bind("click", function() {  
setTimeout(function(){       
    $('container').addClass('active');},1500);
    $container.packery();    
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the delay in a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(function(){       
    $('#container').addClass('active').packery();    
    return false;
},1000); // 1 second
```

The delay is specified in miliseconds. Otherwise it [defaults to zero](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timer-initialization-steps) (see step 5) and just defers it to the next time timers fire.

Comment: The delay is specified after ('active') at 1500. I removed it and placed it where you did, and now the function doesn't, um, function

Comment: @PaulAston Can you create a fiddle illustrating your issue? The timeout belongs where I put it :)

Comment: While I was making a fiddle, I made the change suggested by @ Radney Aaron Alquiza and then implemented your timing change. It works!

[http://jsfiddle.net/Bp3Gr/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp3Gr/11/)

Comment: Gah. It was a 50/50 split. Both of you supplied a vital bit. What's worse - not accepting an answer or selecting one when both were right?

Comment: @PaulAston probably accept the one which was closer to solving your issue.

Answer (score -1):

your $('container') selector is wrong?
if it's an ID, add # before the name.
it it's a class, add . before the name.

EDIT:
the guy above me mentioned the delay, but it's obvious you already have that (1500).
your curly braces just are not indented.

Comment: I thought the container was defined in the var, but I changed it to $('.packery') anyway. No success though, still fires immediately.

Comment: if you want to use the $container you declared on top,
you can reference and add jquery functions to it by doing
$container.addClass('active');
now, if you have firebug, can you console.log('test') inside the settimeout function if it really is running? you might also want to console.log($container) if it really is being referenced.

Comment: That was a real help. Changing to $container.addClass('active'); and then making the delay changes below, has solved the problem.

Comment: the thing is, Benjamin's code breaks the settimeout() because you already have 1500 after adding the class, and then he added 1000 at the end. the 1000 is a floating partner because settimeout is already closed.. anyway, accept whomever u like. :)